# MigLayout: Set equal column width in nested panels with LayoutManagers

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have nested panels using a [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) each.

A panel *outer* with MigLayout with two rows. Each row contains a nested panel (*upper* and *lower*) with the following definition:

```java
JPanel upper = new JPanel(); // External component
add(upper, "cell 0 0,grow"); // "cell 0 1, grow" - for the lower
upper.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][grow]", "[]"));
```

This is the schematic view:

```
   +----------------+---------------------------+
   |                |upper column 1 size        |
   |                v                           |
   |  +-------------+-------------------+       |
   |  |             |                   |       |
   |  |  label1     |     textfield1    |upper  |
   |  |             |                   |       |
   |  +-------------+-------------------+       |
   |                |                           | outer
   |  +-------------v------+------------+       |
   |  |                    |            |       |
   |  |  label2 - (longer) | textfield2 | lower |
   |  |                    |            |       |
   |  +--------------------+------------+       |
   |                       ^                    |
   |                       |lower column 1 size |
   +--------------------------------------------+
```

The text of label2 is longer than the text of label1. Here is what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot of the nested panels]

I want to have the right border of the textfields **aligned**, despite they are in different panels (with separate LayoutManagers)

I tried setting a sizegroup to both column definitions, but this did not result in a change. Which somehow makes sense, as the MigLayouts don't know of each other. (See [size group definition in the whitepaper](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html))

**How can I achieve that the first column of the upper and the lower panel gets the same width, without hard coding a size into the panels?**

What I would not like is to change all these column definitions and hardcode a (the same) fixed width. And the nested panels should stay independent, as they are UI components that we reuse.

Comment: just a quick comment: the general is to not nest if you there's _any_ way to avoid it - not even mig can cope with cross-component layout

Comment: Thanks, I had this impression as well. Does this mean it is not really feasible to reuse GUI "layouted" components?

Comment: @Behe, just wondering: have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Just in case, I've raised the question as GitHub issue: https://github.com/mikaelgrev/miglayout/issues/74

Comment: @VladimirSitnikov I can't remember :-(

Comment: An alternative aproach: Create factories or builder classes which know how to create a new row to your form ui for certain kind of types.